# PostgreSQL add SERIAL column to existing table with values based on ORDER BY

Tags: postgresql

I have a large table (6+ million rows) that I'd like to add an auto-incrementing integer column `sid`, where `sid` is set on existing rows based on an `ORDER BY inserted_at ASC`. In other words, the oldest record based on `inserted_at` would be set to `1` and the latest record would be the total record count. Any tips on how I might approach this?

Comment: Does the table have a `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: Yes, in my specific case primary key `id` is a UUID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a `sid` column and `UPDATE SET ... FROM ... WHERE`:

```
UPDATE test
SET sid = t.rownum
FROM (SELECT id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY inserted_at ASC) as rownum
    FROM test) t
WHERE test.id = t.id
```

Note that this relies on there being a primary key, `id`.
(If your table did not already have a primary key, you would have to make one first.)

---

For example,

```
-- create test table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE test (
    id int PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
    , foo text
    , inserted_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
INSERT INTO test (foo, inserted_at) VALUES
('XYZ', '2019-02-14 00:00:00-00')
, ('DEF', '2010-02-14 00:00:00-00')
, ('ABC', '2000-02-14 00:00:00-00');

-- +----+-----+------------------------+
-- | id | foo |      inserted_at       |
-- +----+-----+------------------------+
-- |  1 | XYZ | 2019-02-13 19:00:00-05 |
-- |  2 | DEF | 2010-02-13 19:00:00-05 |
-- |  3 | ABC | 2000-02-13 19:00:00-05 |
-- +----+-----+------------------------+

ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN sid INT;

UPDATE test
SET sid = t.rownum
FROM (SELECT id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY inserted_at ASC) as rownum
    FROM test) t
WHERE test.id = t.id
```

yields

```
+----+-----+------------------------+-----+
| id | foo |      inserted_at       | sid |
+----+-----+------------------------+-----+
|  3 | ABC | 2000-02-13 19:00:00-05 |   1 |
|  2 | DEF | 2010-02-13 19:00:00-05 |   2 |
|  1 | XYZ | 2019-02-13 19:00:00-05 |   3 |
+----+-----+------------------------+-----+
```

Finally, make `sid` SERIAL ([or, better, an IDENTITY column](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-10-identity-columns/)):

```
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN sid SET NOT NULL;
-- IDENTITY fixes certain issue which may arise with SERIAL
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN sid ADD GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY;
-- ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN sid SERIAL;
```

Comment: I'm using this to create a new `id` column. But this results in new records starting at `id = 1` creating duplicates in the `id`-column. How to prevent that?